# Generate repositories from EF Code First with created DbContext model classes

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, repository-pattern

I'm starting a new project and want to use EF Code First pattern but I also want to use the repository pattern. I have been looking for a way to generate the repositories from the dbcontext models but all answers I've seen so far are for generating repositories from .edmx or DB. I don't want to create an .edmx.

The steps I want to do is this:
1. Write models
2. Generate repositories using t4 templates
3. Write app code from models and repos
4. Run Add-Migration to add migration code
5. Run update-database to update based off migration code

What could I use to tell it to generate t4 templates based on the model classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found how to do it now. Using T4Scaffolding, I am going to be able to generate the repositories as I need. It also allows me to override the default t4 templates and create custom scaffolds too.

Answer (score 0):

There is a NuGet package I created which does this as well, it requires a namespace your models not a edmx file:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/RepositoryGenerator/